# Question about while(!EOF)

Tags: c, stdin, eof

Im reading in values from `stdin` and I want to keep reading the file until I have completed reading it all the way, so I am using

```
while(!EOF){ scanf(...) }
```

However, the code fragment doesn't seem to do anything,

```
while(!EOF){


    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &imageWidth, &imageHeight, &safeRegionStart, &safeRegionWidth);

    printf("---imageWidth=%d imageHeight=%d safeRegionStart=%d safeRegionWidth=%d---\n", imageWidth, imageHeight, safeRegionStart, safeRegionWidth);
    totalP = imageWidth * imageHeight ;
    totalSafeP = imageHeight * safeRegionWidth;


    printf("---total # of pixels: %d Total # of safe Pixels: %d---\n\n", totalP, totalSafeP);

    i=1;

    while(i!=totalP)
    {
        i++;
        scanf("%d", &pixel);
        printf("\nValue of pixel %d", pixel);


    }//End for scanning all pixels*/
}//while loop
```

EDIT: I fixed it

```
while(scanf("%d %d %d %d", &imageWidth, &imageHeight, &safeRegionStart, &safeRegionWidth)==4&&!feof(stdin)) { }
```

`!feof(stdin)` probably isn't necessary.

Comment: Then what does it do? Did you debug it?

Comment: It didn't do anything because while(!EOF) was evaluated to be false, so the while was never executed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`EOF` is only an integer constant. On most systems it is `-1`. `!-1` is `false` and `while(false)` won't do anything.

What you want is to check the return values of `scanf`. `scanf` returns the number of successfully read items and eventually `EOF`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is easy to answer:

EOF is a constant `#define`, e.g. `#define EOF -1`.

So your `while(!EOF)` condition will always be false and the loop won't execute. You need to check the return value of `scanf` against EOF.

You need something like:

```
while(scanf("%d %d %d %d", &imageWidth, &imageHeight, &safeRegionStart, &safeRegionWidth) != EOF){
```

Comment: Actually it should be `scanf("%d %d %d %d",...) == 4`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a variable to hold a char value that can be potentially `EOF`. Something like ..

```
while(4==scanf("%d %d %d %d", &imageWidth, &imageHeight, &safeRegionStart, &safeRegionWidth)) {
//do stuff
}
```

Otherwise !EOF is always false.

Comment: Since that can cause an infinite loop, it should be `scanf("%d %d %d %d",...) == 4`

Comment: Wrong. feof() does not do what you seem to think.

Comment: I see, it needs to be used with fscanf. I don't get anything right today. Am I right ? Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

The loop will never be entered. `EOF` is a constant value which is `-1` (check `stdio.h` for this definition). So `!EOF` is `0` which is false, so it will never be entered.

To check that if the file has ended or not you can use: `if (feof (file_ptr)) break;`

```
while (1)
{
   /* Read file */
   if (feof (file_ptr))
     break;
   /* Do work */
}
```